# Using big Oh notation.

Tags: asymptotics, exponential-function

How to show that $O(x^{1/2} e^{ (log (\frac{x}{c}))^{1/2}})=O(x^{1/2+\epsilon})$ for any $\epsilon>0$?

Comment: Neither (number-theory) nor (analytic-number-theory) is relevant. // Where are your tries?

Answer (score 0):

Since
$$
  y - k = O(\varepsilon^2 y^2)
$$
one has that
for all $\varepsilon$ and $c$
$$
\log \frac{x}{c} = \log x - \log c= O(\varepsilon^2\log^2 x)
$$
which means that
$$
(\log\frac{x}{c})^{\frac 1 2} = O(\varepsilon \log x)
$$
and hence
$$
e^{(\log\frac{x}{c})^{\frac 1 2}} = O(e^{\varepsilon \log x })= O(x^\varepsilon).
$$
The required result follows.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=e^{(\log(x/c))^{1/2}}=e^{\sqrt{\log(x/c)}}$
Then we have $f(x)^{\sqrt{\log(x/c)}}=e^{(\log(x/c))}=x/c$
So we can see that $f(x)^{\sqrt{\log(x/c)}}=x/c$ which means $f(x)=(x/c)^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{\log(x/c)}}}<x^{\epsilon}$ since $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\log(x/c)}}\rightarrow 0$.

Combining all together yields $x^{1/2}e^{(\log(x/c))^{1/2}}<x^{1/2+\epsilon}$
which gives immediately what yu want.